# Azure User Defined Endpoint at Ubuntu not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure

I got a problem with Azure Endpoint using Ubuntu.

SYMPTOMS

Online port scanner reported that port 1194 is closed even though the End point was defined to be open at Azure Web Interface for that VM

SETTINGS:

UFW, aka Ubuntu Firewall is inactive.

No IP Table was defined in Ubuntu

On Azure web management interface, endpoint called VPN, port TCP 443 and UDP 
1194 was set to open, bidirectional allowing direct return. Public and Private port is both 1194, and both 443

lfor and netstat on ubuntu reported thata service is listening on 1194, got NC to listen to 443

DIAGNOSIS

From Ubuntu, I can see the internet. Pinging Google, getting updates works fine.

I can remote into the machine using default port 22, which is a default open endpoint defined by Azure Ubuntu Image

Restarted Ubuntu everytime a setting change.

Tried deleting and  re-creating Endpoint rule, failed

Tried shutting down the VM, and delete and recreate endpoint rule, failed

I CAN Telnet to my local host from Ubuntu via 443.

TROUBLESHOOTING STEPS DEFINED

From my local computer, unable to telnet to the Ubuntu server via 443. Ok on 22, terminated because of protocol mismatch, but that is of course fine.

Online port scanners all report that 1194 was closed and so is 443

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to manually configure the endpoint.

Please check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/?rnd=1 for more information.